# How To Set Model Attributes With Values From A Div In Razor Syntax (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a an Inspector ID in a div I am trying to access so I can get the corresponding UserName out of an IEnumerable called inspectors. There's two ways I can see doing this, either I can set Model.InspectorId to the value in the div or I can reference $("#InspectorDropDown").val() in the query. Neither of these are working because they blend JavaScript, HTML and Razor Syntax in a messy way. Is there are simple solution for this problem?

Here is the dropdown which populates the div with the correct ID

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Inspector, inspectors, "--Select--", new { @id = "InspectorDropDown", @class = "form-control" })
```

Attempt 1:

```
var wrongway = $("#InspectorDropDown").val()

$.post('@Url.Action("SetInspectionDetails", "Inspections")', {

                    inspector: "@inspectors.Where(x => x.Value == wrongway).FirstOrDefault().Text",



                }).done(function(response){
```

This gives an error because in the context of the razor syntax the JavaScript variable is inaccessible.

Attempt 2:

```
@Model.InspectorId = $("#InspectorDropDown").val()
```

This also gives an error because it mixes JavaScript and Razor Syntax.

Is there a simpler way to do this with either JavaScript or Razor Syntax?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between _server-side_ code and _client-side_ code.  That is fundamentally impossible

Comment: It's fundamentally impossible in the way I'm going about it but I do not think it's impossible to access the value I'm looking for. I can reference the div in JavaScript why can't I save that value somewhere?

Comment: Now I have been thinking  about, in the controller, using the ID passed from the div just to look up the inspector in it's repository.

Comment: If you want to talk to the server, you need AJAX.

Comment: SetInspectionDetails is an AJAX call. It's in the controller and is where I'm thinking of accessing the UserName.

Comment: sorry for not including the corresponding controller code since I was trying to do this in the view.

Comment: You can't do it in the view

Comment: Did it in the controller, everything is working now.

Comment: technically you can set a javascipt var to a serialized version of your @inspectors object then use that in your javascript but its really not the best way if you can retrieve the data in your controller instead `var inspectors = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(inspectors));`  or something